# Logging Document Views in SharePoint: How to Save Logs or Create Custom Triggers?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Is there a way to save a log when a user views any document in SharePoint? Alternatively, can we create a custom trigger to log it in a list?

I have used Power Automate, but it does not provide an option to trigger a log when a file is viewed. Additionally, I have tried using the audit log report, but it lacks the necessary features in the site collection audit settings.

Comment: As far as I am there is no trigger for a user viewing a file. You can however collect this kind of usage analytics via different methods afterwards. Get itemAnalytics method of the Graph API is one of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Indeed, there is no trigger action for viewing files in sharepoint, and currently only trigger reminders when changes occur.